c++ Capturing local variable by reference in a lambda, is it ok?

std::list<uint32_t> mylist; 

void someFunc() {

            bool removed = false; 

            mylist.remove_if([&removed, this](const uint32_t & item){ 

               if (item == 1) {
                 removed = true;
                 return true;
               }

               return false; 
  
            }); 
            
            if (removed ) {
                    //  ...  
                    return; 
            }
}

I'm using cpp 11, 'remove_if' from std::list does not return anything versus future versions that do.
Is what I have above acceptable / defined.  I'm capturing a local variable 'removed' by reference, modifying it in the lambda and then using it afterwards.  The lambda is only called within someFunc() so 'removed' should exist for the lifetime of the lambda...
It does seem incorrect to capture a temporary though..  although it works and with no compiler warnings.

Yes, it's ok since you are not accessing removed after its lifetime has ended (which happens when returning from someFunc()).
That problem may occur if you pass a lambda to a function that stores the lambda for execution after the referenced variable has gone out of scope, but again, that is not the case here.

Perfect, thank you!  Makes sense.

@SticilFace You're welcome! Glad it helped!

@SticilFace Welcome to StackOverflow. If an answer solves your problem you could click '✔' to mark it as an accepted answer. With enough rep you can also upvote any helpful answer, as voting and accepting is separate (see here: What should I do when someone answers my question?).
